# get iframe form values using angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

I have simple form from another host `localhost:9000` and my current angular application running from `localhost:4200`

how to get iframe form fields value using angular 4 .

i have tried this below :

**forms from localhost:9000**

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div class="container" id="registerForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="text-align: left;">First Name </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="text-align: left;">Last Name </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In angular app code below :

**app.component.html**

```
<iframe width="100%" #myFrame height="auto" [src]="url | safe"></iframe>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class HomeComponent {

    @ViewChild('myFrame') iframe: ElementRef;

    url: string = "http://localhost:9000";

    save() {
        <-- i want iframe form values here after click save button -->
        let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
        console.log(doc);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: did you solve this ? @chandru

Answer (score 0):

Iframe component

```
 window.parent.postMessage(form.value,'*')
```

- *as domain example.com or use *

in Parent component

```
window.addEventListener("message", formData);
```